# How to set default value for a field in laravel `morphMany` relationship (not database tier)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a model `File` where save files of my app, it like:

```php
class File{
    public const IMAGE_TYPE = 'image';
    public const AUDIO_TYPE = 'audio';
    public const VIDEO_TYPE = 'video';
    public const APPLICATION_TYPE = 'application';

    protected  $fillable = ['path', 'type', 'description', 'order', 'filable_type', 'filable_id'];
}
```

Suppose I have an `Post` model, it like:

```php
class Post{
    public function videos(){
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'filable')
                    ->where('type', File::VIDEO_TYPE);
    }

    public function images(){
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'filable')
                    ->where('type', File::IMAGE_TYPE);
    }
}
```

When I get data of above relationships it's okay 
But when I create a new file of post it is `repetitive` and easily make `mistakes`

```php
    $post->images()->create([
                         'path' => 'my-image.jpg',
                         'type' => File::IMAGE_TYPE,
                     ]);

    $post->videos()->create([
                         'path' => 'my-image.mp3',
                         'type' => File::VIDEO_TYPE,
                     ]);
```

I want it look like:

```php
    $post->images()->create([
                         'path' => 'my-image.jpg',
                     ]);

    $post->videos()->create([
                         'path' => 'my-image.mp3',
                     ]);
```

I don't need declare type per creating `videos` or `images` of a `post`.

How I can accomplish this!

Answer (score 1):

Modal

```
// Change morphMany to hasMAny
public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'fileable')
                ->where('type', File::IMAGE_TYPE);
}
```

Controller

```
  // You can do this 
  $vedioToCreate = $post->videos();
  $vedioToCreate->path = 'my-image.mp3';
  $vedioToCreate->save();

  // Or you can do this 
  $post->videos()->create([
                     'path' => 'my-image.mp3',
                 ]);
```

Comment: I think it isn't solution for my case. I need morphMay for relationship because many model of my app need relate to `File` model

Comment: can you please show me models realted to file model ?

Comment: For example: i have `Account` model (game account), `Post` model there models need relate to `File` model. If i use `hasMany` relationship i need create 2 pivot table for this example but use `morphMany` i just create 1 for there and many models in futures ( sorry if my english is bad)